# Access rights of stored procedures, views and tables (sql server)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, view, access-rights

I have a question about the topic access rights of stored procedures, views and tables.

Users can execute stored procedures and views. If the user needs to update data in a view (this view contains only one base table) do I need to define the usergroup update/insert access rights to the table or view? My intention is, that this usergroup shouldn't have access rights to tables directly.

Can anyone explain me the approach about access rights on stored procedures, views and tables or send me a link with an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

If you grant Insert and Update access to the view, the users will be be able to insert/update data from the view. They will not be able to insert/update directly to the table. However, if there are DENY insert/update permnissions on the underlying table, then the insert/update to the view will fail.

Here's a comprehensive link to permissioning.

[SQL Server permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)